How to manipulate class properties?
I'm trying to create an edit function in Item that will take a parameter of the key (sorry if I get the terminology wrong, but something like title) and replace its value with the second parameter. Here is my code so far:
class Item {
    constructor(title, description, date, done = false) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
        this.done = done;
    }

    edit(property, newValue) {
        // Do something here.
    }
}

const dentist = new Item("Dentist appointment", "With Sally", "19/06/2024")
dentist.edit(title, "Appointment") // May need to pass something else in.
console.log(dentist) 


Try this[property] = newValue

An error is returned when passing in title, but I'm not sure how it should be passed in.

You'll need to pass the name of the property as a string -> dentist.edit("title", "Appointment").  Your code would've worked if title was a variable that held a valid property name.

TYSM for helping.

it could be worth saying that it's a bit overkill to have such a method since you can just change the object properties straight doing dentist.title = "Appointment";

possibly, but i think it'll be more useful when linking up to dom, im making a to-do list

Note that what you ask about are not class properties.

you can access the key with something like this object[]. You can write your edit function as follows
edit(property, newValue) {
  Object.keys(this).map((key)=>{
      if(key===property) this[key] = newValue;
  })

}
You can add a check for extra safety, so that a new property is not added in your object.

This will not work if you call edit("title", "") and then edit("title", "hey")

It would be weird to actually assign your property with empty strings. But then again, the code should hold good for your use case as well.

I think you miss the point about "...and then..."

be my guest and please try this in any online javascript compiler.

You mean you have not tried it yourself? See: https://jsfiddle.net/sp4nodme/
